# We want an video recorder inside the App without opening the native recorder of the phone, as like snapchat do for video recording

Tags: ionic-framework

We have an issue with camera image, when we click the image from camera preview it is taking image larger then camera preview size. We want camera preview and image clicked size same. We are using ionic 3 with camera preview plugin

We want an video recorder inside the App without opening the native recorder of the phone, as like snapchat do for video recording

### Below is the Code what we have done

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPage, App, Content, NavController, Platform, ViewController, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";
// import {CameraPreview} from "@ionic-native/camera-preview";
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewPictureOptions, CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewDimensions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { Base64 } from '@ionic-native/base64';


import { TabsService } from "../../util/tabservice";
import { ShowPhotoPage } from '../show-photo/show-photo';
import { PhotoLibrary } from "@ionic-native/photo-library";
import { UnsplashItUtil } from "../../util/unsplashItutil";
import { ImageService } from "../../util/imageservice";
import { ImageEntity } from "../../util/ImageEntity";
import { Base64ToGallery } from "@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery";
import { NativeStorage } from "@ionic-native/native-storage";
import { HomePage } from "../home/home";
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TabsPage } from "../tabs/tabs";
const MEDIA_FILES_KEY = 'mediaFiles';
/**
 * Generated class for the ManagephotoPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-managephoto',
  templateUrl: 'managephoto.html',
})
export class ManagephotoPage {
  mediaFiles = [];
  @ViewChild('myvideo') myVideo: any;

  srcPhoto;
  segment = "photo";
  images = [];
  selectedPhoto;

  @ViewChild(Content)
  content: Content;
  frmWedInv: any;

  tabBarElement: any;

  imageURI: any;
  isImageSelected: boolean = false;

  wedNam: any;
  wedTheme: any;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage,
    public cameraPreview: CameraPreview,
    public platform: Platform,
    public tabsService: TabsService,
    private photoLibrary: PhotoLibrary,
    private imageService: ImageService,
    private viewController: ViewController, private media: Media,
    private app: App, public unsplash: UnsplashItUtil,
    private mediaCapture: MediaCapture, private file: File,
    private camera: Camera, private base64: Base64, public nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {
    let self = this;

    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('#tabs .tabbar.show-tabbar');
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';

    this.nativeStorage.getItem('themeImg').then((s) => {
      this.wedNam = s.property1;
      this.wedTheme = s.property2;
    }
    ).catch(ex => {

    });

    this.frmWedInv = this.navParams.get("frmWedInv");
    console.log("visited camera");
  }

  chooseFile() {
    console.log('gdf');
    let options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 1280,
      targetHeight: 1280,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };


    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((img) => {
      // this.imageURI = img;
      this.imageURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img;
      this.navCtrl.push(ShowPhotoPage, { photo: this.imageURI });
      // this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then((base64File: string) => {

      // }, (err) => {
      //   console.log(err);
      // });

    }).catch((reason) => {
      console.log(reason);
    });
  }


  backLnk() {
    this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
  }
  back1() {
    this.stopCamera();
    this.navCtrl.pop();
    //this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }

  flashMode = "off";

  changeSegment(value) {
    this.segment = value;

    if (value == "photo" || value == 'video') {
      this.startCamera();
    } else {
      this.stopCamera();
    }
  }

  flash() {
    console.log(this.flashMode)
    if (this.flashMode == 'off') {
      this.flashMode = 'on'
    }
    else if (this.flashMode == 'on') {
      this.flashMode = 'auto'
    } else {
      this.flashMode = 'off'
    }

    this.setFlashMode();

  }

  setFlashMode() {
    this.cameraPreview.setFlashMode(this.flashMode).then(() => {

    }).catch(() => {

    });
  }

  takePicture() {
    let self = this;
    var number = window.innerHeight / 5;
    const pictureOpts = {
      quality: 80,
      width: 1280,
      height: 400,
      // width: this.platform.width(),
      // height: this.platform.height() / 1.9,
      // targetWidth:this.platform.width(),
      // targetHeight:this.platform.height() / 1.9,
      // correctOrientation: true,
      // encodingType:this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    };
this.cameraPreview.getSupportedPictureSizes().then(data=>{
  data.forEach(element => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(element));
  });
})


    this.cameraPreview.takePicture(pictureOpts).then(base64PictureData => {
      //   console.log("aqui takando foto", base64PictureData)
      alert(JSON.stringify(pictureOpts));
      self.srcPhoto = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64PictureData;
      console.log(this.navParams.get("topCamera") + " oooooooooooo")
      this.navCtrl.push(ShowPhotoPage, { photo: self.srcPhoto, topCamera1: this.navParams.get("topCamera") });
      // const index = this.viewCtrl.index;
      // this.navCtrl.remove(index);
      self.cameraPreview.hide().then(() => {

      })

    });
  }


  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('#tabs .tabbar.show-tabbar');
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.unsplash.getListOfImages(100).then(list => {
        this.images = list;
        this.selectedPhoto = this.images[0].mediumSizeUrl;
      })
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.images));

      // this.images =Array( this.imageService.getImages());


    }, 300);

    if (this.segment == 'photo') {
      this.startCamera();
    }

  }

  goToPhoto() {

    this.navCtrl.push(ShowPhotoPage, { photo: this.selectedPhoto });
  }

  changePhoto(newImage) {

    this.selectedPhoto = newImage.mediumSizeUrl;
    this.content.scrollToTop(300);

  }


  back() {
    // alert();
    this.stopCamera();
    // this.navCtrl.pop();
    // this.app.getRootNav().getActiveChildNav().select(0);
    // this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
    // try {
    //   this.app.getRootNav().getActiveChildNav().select(0);
    //   // this.viewController.dismiss();
    // } catch (e) {

    // }

  }

  stopCamera() {
    try {
      this.cameraPreview.stopCamera().catch(e => {

      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  }

  getPosition() {
    return (this.platform.height() / 1.9) - 20
  }

  getHeight() {
    return this.platform.height() - this.getPosition() - 64;
  }

  cmrBtnPos() {
    return (this.platform.height() / 1.9) + 100;
  }

  glryBtnPos() {
    return (this.platform.height() / 1.9) + 125;
  }

  startCamera() {


    this.stopCamera();







    this.cameraPreview.startCamera({
      x: 0,
      y: 50,
      width: this.platform.width(),
      height: this.platform.height() / 3,
      camera: 'back',
      tapPhoto: false,
      tapToFocus: true,
      previewDrag: false,
      toBack: false,

      //alpha: 0
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("camera started")
      this.setFlashMode();
    }).catch(() => {
      console.log("camera error")
    })


  }

  refresh() {
    this.cameraPreview.switchCamera();
  }

  // ionViewDidLoad() {
  //   console.log('ionViewDidLoad ManagephotoPage');
  // }

  public unregisterBackButtonAction: any;


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ManagephotoPage');
    this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res => {
      this.mediaFiles = JSON.parse(res) || [];
    })
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('#tabs .tabbar.show-tabbar');
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';
    this.initializeBackButtonCustomHandler();
    console.log("Enter")
  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'flex';
    this.stopCamera();
    // Unregister the custom back button action for this page
    this.unregisterBackButtonAction && this.unregisterBackButtonAction();
  }



  initializeBackButtonCustomHandler(): void {
    this.unregisterBackButtonAction = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
      console.log('Prevent Back Button Page Change');
    }, 101); // Priority 101 will override back button handling (we set in app.component.ts) as it is bigger then priority 100 configured in app.component.ts file */
  }

  captureVideo() {
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = {
      limit: 1,
      duration: 10
    }
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then((res: MediaFile[]) => {
      let capturedFile = res[0];
      let fileName = capturedFile.name;
      let dir = capturedFile['localURL'].split('/');
      dir.pop();
      let fromDirectory = dir.join('/');
      var toDirectory = this.file.dataDirectory;

      this.file.copyFile(fromDirectory, fileName, toDirectory, fileName).then((res) => {
        this.storeMediaFiles([{ name: fileName, size: capturedFile.size }]);
      }, err => {
        console.log('err: ', err);
      });
    },
      (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err));
  }
  storeMediaFiles(files) {
    this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res => {
      if (res) {
        let arr = JSON.parse(res);
        arr = arr.concat(files);
        this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(arr));
      } else {
        this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(files))
      }
      this.mediaFiles = this.mediaFiles.concat(files);
    })
  }
  play(myFile) {

    if (myFile.name.indexOf('.wav') > -1) {
      const audioFile: MediaObject = this.media.create(myFile.localURL);
      audioFile.play();
    } else {
      let path = this.file.dataDirectory + myFile.name;
      let url = path.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
      let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
      video.src = url;
      console.log(url);
      video.play();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any one can help